# how do I configure an end time for systemd timers

Tags: timer, systemd, coreos

I'm using CoreOS and SystemD timers to run my reports...

I have certain monitoring reports that need to run every 3 hours for the next 12 hours, running on the half hour. That's pretty simple to implement if I want to be awake at 1230 to stop the reports.

Is there a "terminate timer" option or something similar in the systemd timers>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to terminate systemd services after a certain amount of time.

Use the `RuntimeMaxSec` option for `Type=simple` services:

```
[Unit]
Description=Terminate simple Service Test

[Service]
Type=simple
RuntimeMaxSec=5
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 10
```

Use the `TimeoutStartSec` for `Type=oneshot` services:

```
[Unit]
Description=Terminate oneshot Service Test

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=5
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 10
```

Both services will be terminated after 5 seconds before the sleep timer reaches 10 seconds.

Details on `RuntimeMaxSec` and `TimeoutStartSec` can be found here:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add the following to the service file's [Unit] directives:

```
JobTimeoutSec=43200
```

You could probably just write a wrapper script to terminate the process after 12 hours or use `timeout 12h COMMAND [ARG]...`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write another timer that is scheduled to run at the shutdown times you would like. They can run a service which stops the you want to top, by running `ExecStart=/bin/systemctl stop other.service` in the service file called your shutdown timer.

I reviewed the docs for `JobTimeoutSec` from `man systemd.unit` and doesn't seem like quite the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use RuntimeMaxSec can result in the service not stopping at the right time. Per example, if you want to start your service at a specific time (8AM) and one day you have to start the service manually due to a failure. In that case, the service will not finish at the time you expect, it will finish at timestart+RuntimeMaxSec.

To solve this issue, you can create another service with parameter *Conflicts=test.service*:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop Test service
Conflicts=test.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "stopping test service"'
WorkingDirectory=/root
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
User=root
```

and include a timer for executing the stop service at a specific time:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run stop test service

[Timer]
# Run every day at 23:55h
OnCalendar=Mon..Sun 23:55

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Because the service *stop* is in conflict with the service *test*, the first will stop the latter if it is running.